# HTML & CSS Comment List

Tags: html, css

I have tried tried coding a comment list where the avatar is supposed to display on the left, and the name and comment are supposed to display on the right. Any help solving the issue is appreciated.

**Outcome**

[image]

**Desired Outcome**

[image]

**HTML**

```
    <section>
    <div class='friend'>
        <h3>John Smith</h3>
        <p>Just another comment</p>
        <img src='http://media.dunkedcdn.com/assets/prod/13/700x0-5_p17o72pss9bbmvuspb1gl61ot23.jpg'>
    </div>
    <div class='friend'>
        <h3>John Smith</h3>
        <p>Just another comment</p>
        <img src='http://media.dunkedcdn.com/assets/prod/13/700x0-5_p17o72pss9bbmvuspb1gl61ot23.jpg'>
    </div>
    <div class='friend'>
        <h3>John Smith</h3>
        <p>Just another comment</p>
        <img src='http://media.dunkedcdn.com/assets/prod/13/700x0-5_p17o72pss9bbmvuspb1gl61ot23.jpg'>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
  body {
    font: 14px/20px 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #333;
}
    a {
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

    h1, h2, h3 {
    font-weight: 400;
    }

    h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
    }

    h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
    }

    h3 {
    font-size: 20px;
    }

    img {
      height: auto;
      width: 100%;
    }

    section {
    padding: 30px 60px;
    }

    .friend img {
    height: 70px;
    width: 100px;
    display: block;
    }
```

Comment: well, there's no bug from where I see it, your HTML+CSS is having the proper behaviour. The keyword here would be "float" ... try to help yourself first :-)

Comment: Semantically speaking, a list of comments is exactly that, a _list_.  You should consider wrapping your elements in list tags.  Not necessary for the effect that you are going for; however, it is the correct way to list items.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML Comment List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16696802/html-comment-list)

Answer (score 3):

you would want to add float to your image 
like

```
.friend img{
 float:left;
}
```

here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GaNDq/)

Answer (score 0):

Float your `h3` and `p` tags to the right.

```
.friend h3, .friend p {
    float: right;
}
```

Altneratively, have the image first and float it to the left.

http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use inline-block instead of float in CSS with vertical-align, here you can see the result: http://jsfiddle.net/gG5uv/3/.

```
.friend img {
    height: 70px;
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.friend .data {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

I've also added a semantic separation between image and personal data of each item creating a `div` with class `data`.

Answer (score 0):

Hey You can check your solution here at http://jsbin.com/edit/637/.
Just a few changes in your code.

HTML

```
<div class="friend">
  <img id ='friend-image' src='http://media.dunkedcdn.com/assets/prod/13/700x0-5_p17o72pss9bbmvuspb1gl61ot23.jpg'>
                <div id="friend-bio">
                    <h4>John Smith</h4>
                    <p>Just another comment</p>
                </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="friend">
  <img id ='friend-image' src='http://media.dunkedcdn.com/assets/prod/13/700x0-5_p17o72pss9bbmvuspb1gl61ot23.jpg'>
                <div id="friend-bio">
                    <h4>John Smith</h4>
                    <p>Just another comment</p>
                </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="friend">
  <img id ='friend-image' src='http://media.dunkedcdn.com/assets/prod/13/700x0-5_p17o72pss9bbmvuspb1gl61ot23.jpg'>
                <div id="friend-bio">
                    <h4>John Smith</h4>
                    <p>Just another comment</p>
                </div>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
.friend #friend-image {
    border: 1px solid #F0F2F8;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    height: 85px;
    width: 84px;
}
#main #friend #friend-bio {
    float: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: -7px 0 0 20px;
    width: 454px;
}
#main #friend #friend-bio h4 {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0 0 5px;
}
```