# HTML Comment List

Tags: html, css

I have tried tried coding a comment list where the avatar is supposed to display on the left, and the name and comment are supposed to display on the right. Any help solving the issue is appreciated.

**Outcome**

[image]

**Desired Outcome**

[image]

**HTML**

```
    <section>
    <div class='friend'>
        <h3>John Smith</h3>
        <p>Just another comment</p>
        <img src='http://media.dunkedcdn.com/assets/prod/13/700x0-5_p17o72pss9bbmvuspb1gl61ot23.jpg'>
    </div>
    <div class='friend'>
        <h3>John Smith</h3>
        <p>Just another comment</p>
        <img src='http://media.dunkedcdn.com/assets/prod/13/700x0-5_p17o72pss9bbmvuspb1gl61ot23.jpg'>
    </div>
    <div class='friend'>
        <h3>John Smith</h3>
        <p>Just another comment</p>
        <img src='http://media.dunkedcdn.com/assets/prod/13/700x0-5_p17o72pss9bbmvuspb1gl61ot23.jpg'>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
  body {
    font: 14px/20px 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #333;
}
    a {
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

    h1, h2, h3 {
    font-weight: 400;
    }

    h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
    }

    h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
    }

    h3 {
    font-size: 20px;
    }

    img {
      height: auto;
      width: 100%;
    }

    section {
    padding: 30px 60px;
    }

    .friend img {
    height: 70px;
    width: 100px;
    display: block;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried it with floats? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Place the `<img>`s *before* the paragraphs (where they seem to belong anyway).  Then have them `float: left`.  You can add a margin to the right of them as well to create more spacing if you like.

http://jsfiddle.net/Q8emr/

Comment: I won't tell IE6/7, if you don't. :)